# React Router make Link not active for sub routes

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have a react router app which has this simple navigation:

```
    React.DOM.ul(
      {className: 'navigation'},
      React.DOM.li(
        {},
        React.createElement(
          Link,
          {to: '/', activeClassName: 'active'},
          React.DOM.i({className: 'fa fa-tachometer'}),
          'Dashboard'
        )
      ),
      React.DOM.li(
        {},
        React.createElement(
          Link,
          {to: '/help', activeClassName: 'active'},
          React.DOM.i({className: 'fa fa-life-ring'}),
          'Help'
        )
      )
    )
```

When I load `/` The dashboard Link is active as one would expect. Clicking Help loads `/help`  and makes the Help link active, but leaves the Dashboard link active as well.

From what I can tell `/help` still matches `/` with `Link` assuming that I want active to appear on the entire hierarchy for a route. Is it possible to disable this behavour?

My Router:

```
  React.createElement(Route, {
    path: '/',
    component: Layout
  },
    React.createElement(IndexRoute, {component: Dashboard}),
    React.createElement(Route, {path: '/help', component: Help})
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the property `onlyActiveOnIndex` for the `Link` to `true` it will only be active if the current path exactly matches the links path.

For me this fixes the problem by setting it on the dashboard link e.g.

```
    React.createElement(
      Link,
      {to: '/', activeClassName: 'active', onlyActiveOnIndex: true},
      React.DOM.i({className: 'fa fa-tachometer'}),
      'Dashboard'
    )
```